# Controlling Emission Shader via Animation Nodes Falloff

Tags: animation-nodes, emission

I hope you doin' alright.

I am trying to give an emission shader to instanced object as you see in the image below. Location of the falloff going to determine the color and/or intensity of the shader. I have been trying to find a solution but, ones that I found confuses me more. Long story short how can I manipulate the shader or shaders to gives me that emission where the falloff is and dark in the rest?

I have added the blender file here:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were completely on the right track.

Hopefully you are happy with a shader solution (if you want a "just" animation nodes solution, let me know).

Just add this material to your instanced object:

[image]

Basically i just use the color information you already fill right with animation nodes to decide whether to use the cyan or the gray color via the fac value of the mix shader.
I just change the cam a bit and animated the falloff.

then you get something like this:

https://youtu.be/Uw2CvY38hAE

here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome